# How to do calculation of two values with commas?

Tags: php

I have two value and I want to do calculation of those values.

For example :

```
$a = '750,000.00';
$b = '763,000.00';
echo $a + $b;
```

and I am getting the result 1513 which is wrong.. The output must be 1513000.

How to do such calculations?

Comment: You are adding 2 strings together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to eliminate the commas before the strings are interpreted as float values:

```
$a = '750,000.00';
$b = '763,000.00';
echo str_replace(',', '', $a) + str_replace(',', '', $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php):

```
// replaces all , with nothing
echo str_replace(',','',$a) + str_replace(',','',$b);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of posting a duplicate answer? @Flinsch, already wrote the same answer.

Comment: @Starx: Apparently our answers were written within 22 seconds, pardon me for not checking for a new answer within the last half minute. By the way the requester might be interested in the additional link to the php documentation as it seems he is a php beginner.

Comment: you might have been unaware of the situation, but I would like to tell you that Stackoverflow Community really tries a lot harder to avoid such duplicates. If users like you become aware of this, you will helping this community a lot. You may have edited @Flinsch answer and placed the link, to complete it. Rep farming is not the game that is played on SO. (I learned this in a very unfair way, but a lesson learnt is learnt).

Answer (score -3):

The following converts a String to Int:

```
<?php
$a = (int)'750,000.00';
$b = (int)'763,000.00';
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

Or String to Float as mentioned by [Flinsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480304/flinsch)

```
<?php
$a = (float)'750,000.00';
$b = (float)'763,000.00';
echo $a + $b;
?>
```

However, you may want to take localisation into account (different writing of numbers in different parts of the world).
My Belgian localisation settings outcome this as "1.513" instead of 1.513.000

Comment: `(int)'750,000.00'` is `750`, not `750000`.

Comment: I think he wants to add floats rather than ints. ;)

Comment: `(float)'750,000.00'` is *also* `750`.  When you cast a string to a number in PHP, it's the same operation as calling [`intval`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) / [`floatval`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php), which process the string from the left and *stop* at the first unprocessable character, i.e. the comma.  This code will simply not work.